# Fastest way to create long video from 1 image with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

What is the fastest way to create a video with long duration (1 hour), from a single image?
Here is what I have now:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -t 3600 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=640:480 image.mp4
```

But it's taking too long in my case, around 40 minutes. The image size I am using is `800KB`.

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: So it takes 40 minutes to render a lengthy mp4 from a single jpg image? Where the video is something like 10 minutes of just image? Or is it taking that long for the video to render, and the duration is just a minute or so?

Comment: Yes it's the first one, it takes 40 minutes to render a lengthy mp4 from a single jpg image, I tried compressing the image down to `150KB` and it's 4 times faster now, but would be great if it can go faster.

Comment: Should be able to go faster, unless it is the encoder. Videos rendered in say Windows Movie Maker or other video programs, are very fast. Even random programs on the internet can do that way faster.

Comment: You're right, that's why I wondered and asked here.

Comment: I googled and found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx not much help. Also I was thinking maybe the lack of sound might be an issue...